# How to concatenate a datafile with four columns

Tags: opencv, gnuplot

My data file has four columns because `opencv` saves elements in an `n x 4` form in xml when exporting a `cv::Mat` to xml.

How can I concatenate these four columns into one?

```
reset

set terminal postscript eps enhanced
set output 'imp.eps'
set pm3d
set palette model HSV defined ( 0 0 1 1, 1 1 1 1 )
set style data histogram
set colorbox user
set origin 0.0,0.10
set size ratio 0 1,0.8
set colorbox horizontal origin graph 0.0, -0.15, 0 size graph 1, 0.05, 0 noborder 

set xrange [0:4096]
plot 'var_imp_first_run.data' using 1

set output
```

I have 4094 elements, and this example creates an histogram where the first 1024 is plotted. I need to append column 2 from x=1024:2048.  Please ignore the colorbox stuff; I'm just playing around to learn `gnuplot`.

I found out that following solve my problem above.

```
set xrange  [0:4096]
plot newhistogram at 0, 'var_imp_first_run.data' every:: 7 using 1,\
  newhistogram at 1024,'var_imp_first_run.data' every:: 7 using 2,\
   newhistogram at 2048,'var_imp_first_run.data' every:: 7 using 3,\
      newhistogram at 3072,'var_imp_first_run.data' every:: 7 using 4;
```

Then I found out that it was not what I wanted, because the data are arranged as entries,

```
x1,x2,x3,x4
x5,x6,x7,x8
and so on.
```

So what I really need is a histogram that plots the rows before columns. Is it possible?

Comment: Thanks @edwin.  I figured out plot newhistogram at 0, 'var_imp_first_run.data' every:: 7 using 1,\
  newhistogram at 1024,'var_imp_first_run.data' every:: 7 using 2,\
   newhistogram at 2048,'var_imp_first_run.data' every:: 7 using 3,\
   newhistogram at 3072,'var_imp_first_run.data' every:: 7 using 4;

Comment: Sorry what do you mean with data arranged as entries?

Comment: Are you on a linux/unix/OSX platform, or on Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to read

```
x1
x2
x3
```

instead of

```
x1,x2,x3
```

Then (assuming you are on *nix) use

```
plot 'cat var_imp_first_run.data | tr "," "\n" |' using 1
```

This is calling the following command and reading the output via the pipe at the end:

```
cat var_imp_first_run.data | tr "," "\n"
```

Here, `tr` is just transcribing commas as newlines.

Comment: Not on a unix system. But thanks anyway. Think im generating my data in a easier way to import into gnuplot instead.